# How selenium standalone server up in Selenium automatically and why not with Protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In **selenium**, we do not need to run '*webdriver-manager start*' command to start the server. but it will start automatically. And in **protractor** we have to run '*webdriver-manager start*' command to start the server if we use '*seleniumAddress:''*' in our conf file.

Can some please help to understand this situation.

Thanks in Advance?

Comment: Please comment if you do not understand the question? . don't down vote if do not know the scope/depth of question

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run your test using `sauce labs` or `browser stack`, the required browser will be on some remote machine.In such scenario, you want to mention the `seleniumAddress` with the url where the selenium server is up and running.